# How to publish offline pages?

Tags: posts, offline

I saved many pages offline with firefox.

Those pages have two parts, a html file and a files directory that contain images, js etc.

What's the easiest way to publish those offline pages on my WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a super easy way to import content that's saved in this manner. If you have a lot of pages with a similar structure, you may want to look into writing a script that can parse your HTML and add the images the WP way - through the Media Library. Depending on the JS you have on each page, if it's similar or identical across pages that's not too hard to enqueue, but if it's unique to each page it will take time to isolate the conditions and only enqueue on the appropriate page.

So, if you have a few dozen pages, it's likely that rebuilding them in the Block Editor will be the fastest approach (and then for the JS, you'll need to create a child theme or a plugin to enqueue on the appropriate pages). If you have more than that, writing a custom script to parse everything may save some time.

Comment: I found a workaround of sorts. Open the offline page in a browser, print the page as PDF, display the PDF on WordPress with a PDF plugin.

Comment: Keep in mind PDFs are less mobile friendly than live text, and may not be as accessible to all users, but at least it's a start. :)